# Single quote string interpolation to access a file in linux

Tags: ruby

> How do I make the parameter `file` of the method `sound` become the file name of the .fifo >extension using single quotes? I've searched up and down, and tried many different >approaches, but I think I need a new set of eyes on this one.
>
> def sound(file)
>        @cli.stream_audio('audio\file.fifo')
>      end

Alright so I finally got it working, might not be the correct way but this seemed to do the trick. First thing, there may have been some white space interfering with my file parameter. Then I used the File.join option that I saw posted here by a few different people.

I used a bit of each of the answers really, and this is how it came out:

```
    def sound(file)
    file = file.strip
    file = File.join('audio/',"#{file}.fifo")
    @cli.stream_audio(file) if File.exist? file
    end
```

Works like a charm! :D

Comment: Why do you need it to be single quotes?!

Comment: You seem to be aware of the difference between single and double quotes with respect to interpolation. And you are still not aware that  interpolation works with double quotation only? That looks kind of contradictory to me.

Comment: Even if you are on Windows OS, Ruby recognizes forward slash as separator. You do not need to use backslash for file access/manipulation.

Comment: The whole point of `File.join` is to get rid of backslashes and forward slashes, so you should simply use `File.join('audio',"#{file}.fifo")`. Get rid of the `\` after `audio`.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby interpolation requires that you use double quotes.

Is there a reason you need to use single quotes?

```
def sound(FILE)
  @cli.stream_audio("audio/#{FILE}.fifo")
end
```

As Charles Caldwell stated in his comment, the best way to get cross-platform file paths to work correctly would be to use `File.join`. Using that, your method would look like this:

```
def sound(FILE)
  @cli.stream_audio(File.join("audio", "#{FILE}.fifo"))
end
```

Comment: Hmm, well I thought this as well but for some reason it isn't working as I intended. The ('audio\file.fifo') works if it's the direct file, but not if it's a variable with a string that's the same file name.

Comment: That's because you are using \. Use / instead.

Comment: or ``\\`` (escape the backslash)

Comment: Or `File.join("audio", "#{file}.fifo")` for cross platform portability

Comment: Even if you are on Windows OS, Ruby recognizes forward slash as separator. You do not need to use backslash for file access/manipulation.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell The problem seems to be the backslash (although the original question had a forward slash). Maybe you should add your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: In this answer the backslash will undo the interpolation: `"audio\#{FILE}.fifo" #=> "audio\#{FILE}.fifo"`

Comment: @Mischa I'm working on an answer that explains what is going on. =)

Comment: @Mischa Good catch, I updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your usage of file path separators. You are using a `\`. Whereas this may not seem like a big deal, it actually is when used in Ruby strings.

When you use `\` in a single quoted string, nothing happens. It is evaluated as-is:

```
puts 'Hello\tWorld' #=> Hello\tWorld
```

Notice what happens when we use double quotes:

```
puts "Hello\tWorld" #=> "Hello    World"
```

The `\t` got interpreted as a tab. That's because, much like how Ruby will interpolate `#{}` code in a double quote, it will also interpret `\n` or `\t` into a new line or tab. So when it sees `"audio\file.fifo"` it is actually seeing `"audio"` with a `\f` and `"ile.fifo"`. It then determines that `\f` means 'form feed' and adds it to your string. [Here is a list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) of escape sequences. It is for C++ but it works across most languages.

As @sawa pointed out, if your escape sequence does not exist (for instance `\y`) then it will just remove the `\` and leave the 'y'.

```
"audio\yourfile.fifo" #=> audioyourfile.fifo
```

There are three possible solutions:

1. Use a forward slash:

   ```
   "audio/#{file}.fifo"
   ```

   The forward slash will be interpreted as a file path separator when passed to the system. I do most my work on Windows which uses `\` but using `/` in my code is perfectly fine.
2. Use `\\`:

   ```
   "audio\\#{file}.fifo"
   ```

   Using a double `\\` escapes the `\` and causes it to be read as you intended it.
3. Use [`File.join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-join):

   ```
   File.join("audio", "#{file}.fifo")
   ```

   This will output the parameters with whatever file separator is setup as in the `File::SEPARATOR` constant.

Comment: Using a backslash in strings is an issue in every programming language I've ever encountered, not just Ruby. It's traditionally an escape of the following character.

Comment: You are a bit wrong. 1. `"\f"` has special (escaped) meaning. 2. When escape does not correspond to a special meaning, the escape is ignored. It does not raise an error. For example, `"\q"` is evaluated as `"q"`.